# Correct set notation for "all integers which are not multiples of 7"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What is correct set notation for "all integers which are not multiples of $7$"? My best guess is:

$$ \{ x : (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z})(\neg(7k = x)) \}$$

Or

$$ \{ x : \neg(\exists k \in \mathbb{Z})(7k = x) \}$$

However this seems unlike other examples I have seen.

Is there are proper way to denote this set in set notation?

Comment: Curly brackets \{  and \} (in math mode).  Your ways are fine. Words are better.

Comment: They're both correct. In general: $$\neg (\forall x \in X) P(x) \iff (\exists x\in X) \neg P(x)$$

Comment: What's wrong with (x mod 7 is different than 0)?

Comment: Don't forget about the simplest one: $\{ x : \text{x is not a multiple of 7} \}$.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting (somewhat pedantically) is that when you say "all numbers" you do mean, apparently, all *integers*. Although the language of "not multiples" would not lead the reader to suspect you were quantifying over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, it *is* possible to believe (as I initially did) that you were quantifying over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: To word the point @BenjaminDickman made in another way: What is the universe of $x$?

Comment: You can use greatest common divisor notation: {x∈ℤ : (x, 7) = 1}

Comment: What is wrong with using English?  I would express the set of all integers that are not divisible by 7 as "the set of all integers that are not divisible by 7"

Comment: Or that set of integers which does not contain integers which can be factored in terms of 7. That gives a different view and it might help creating another set notation but pretty long.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

For starters, you should be using curly braces $\{\}$ for sets, and what you have is fine, but generally the clean abbreviation would be:
$$ \mathbb{Z}-7\mathbb{Z}$$

This is because $-$ denotes set difference and $7\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the set of integer multiples of $7$.

Comment: Or $\mathbb{Z} \setminus 7\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Note that for sets $A$ and $B$ sometimes the notation $A-B$ may be used in another sense, namely for the set of all differences $a-b$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ (clearly this requires that $A$ and $B$ come from a context where there is some additive (abelian) group structure).

Comment: In this case I'd prefer $\Bbb Z - 7\Bbb Z$ over $\Bbb Z \setminus 7\Bbb Z$, since the latter might be confused with $\Bbb Z / 7\Bbb Z$, which is a completely different set.

Comment: If you are worried about confusion with quotient, there’s $\mathbb Z\smallsetminus7\mathbb Z$ (\smallsetminus). I’d never use $-$ to denote set difference in the same context where I am using other arithmetic operations to act pointwise on the set, such as in $7\mathbb Z$, per  Jeppe Stig Nielsen’s comment.

Comment: There are frequently multiple options for mathematical notation, and the best practice is to be consistent and be aware of possible sources of confusion. If you're talking about two different things that could potentially be confused, pick a notation that distinguishes them.

Comment: It's saddening to see a basically wrong answer getting 50 upvotes. No bad feelings when someone writes $-$ instead of $\setminus$ in a colloquial environment, but it's not o.k. when someone is answering exactly the question at hand.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter plenty of people use $-$ in both colloquial and professional environments. I don't see why this is "basically wrong".

Comment: I have seen and heard professional mathematicians among their peers use $A-B$ to mean $A\backslash B$.

Comment: "Basically wrong?"  Give me a break @ChristianBlatter. It's an extremely common notation.  A bit old-fashioned, maybe, and can be misleading depending on the context, but nothing wrong with it.  E.g. Ahlfors uses it.

Answer (score 102):

I'd generally go with $\{x\in\mathbb{Z}: 7 \nmid x\}$, though this does presuppose familiarity with the $\mid \, \nmid$ notation.

Comment: In fact, every notation requires familiarity to use it.

Answer (score 31):

My preferred notation is the "not divides" symbol $a \nmid b$ what means "a not divides b". But you can achieve the same meaning by different ways, by example:

$$\{n\in\Bbb Z: (\nexists k\in\Bbb Z :n/k=7)\}$$

or

$$\{n\in\Bbb Z:n\not\equiv 0\pmod 7\}$$

But the common notation is

$$\{n\in\Bbb Z:7\nmid n\}$$

Comment: $n/7 \notin \mathbb{Z}$ seems a bit more concise than the first version.

Comment: Of all answers, first one here is by far easiest to read and understand for math noobs like me.

Answer (score 26):

Of course, you could always use $$\{ x \in \mathbb{Z} : \text{$x$ is not a multiple of $7$} \}$$

If you think the notation will get in the way of what you're trying to say, then discard the notation!

Answer (score 15):

The most accurate translation of the English condition would be
$$
\left\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:\frac n7\not\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$$

Comment: This is also very succint and clear. +1

Answer (score 11):

I think the vertical line should be used in sets. This is how it's usually done:

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid \forall z \in \mathbb{Z}: x \neq 7z \}$$

First part naming some elements, then after the pipe comes the conditions for those elements. I actually have never seen the colon used instead of the pipe before in any lecture material or mathematical book. I think their usage is different.

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z} \mid 7 \nmid x \}$$

Is another shorter form, but as others said, it required knowledge of the $\nmid$ symbol.

Comment: I don't think you should make the vertical line do double duty as both *such that* and *divides* in the same breath.

Comment: @Zelphir - Your experience is rather limited, then. ":" is the older notation. It is less popular now, but as Era points out, if "|" is being used for some other purpose in the expression, many people will fall back on ":" as the "such that" so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Aha, thanks, didn't know that!

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility (more wordy but to me clearer):

$$\{x \in ℤ:x \neq 7k \quad \forall k∈ℤ\}$$

Comment: Isn't this almost the same as the first line in the question?

Comment: Yes but to my eyes at least this is the clearest answer as it uses the least technical notation.

Comment: A professor of mine strongly disliked notation like this due to $k$ being used before it is defined.

Comment: @filmor that is quite strange, since this is standard notation

Comment: @user I don't believe it is standard to write the forall symbol after its use. It is certainly common in *spoken English* to say e.g. "$x$ is not equal to $7k$ for any $k$", but $x\ne7k\ \forall k\in\Bbb Z$ is just plain wrong, and is downright misleading if it's not the only quantifier (how to parse $\exists x\in\Bbb Z, x\ne7k\ \forall k\in\Bbb Z$?). Quantifier symbols *always* precede their formulas, with appropriate parentheses to delimit their scope if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

The only issue with what you wrote is that you didn't specify what set the $x$ should come from. For example, $x$ could be $1.5$, since $1.5$ isn't an integer multiple of 7. More correct would be

$$ \{ x\in \mathbb{Z} : (\forall k \in \mathbb{Z})(\neg(7k = x)) \}$$

Of course, in terms of simplicity, as others have noted, there are more compact notations for divisibility that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

What about:
{7j+k (∀j∈Z) (∀k∈{1,2,3,4,5,6})}
?